# If $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix over $\Bbb R$ with $\det(A+I)=1+\det A$ then which is correct:

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is  a $2\times 2$ matrix over $\Bbb R$ with $\det(A+I)=1+\det A$ then which is correct:

- $\det A=0$
- $A=0$
- $\text{trace A}=0$
- $A$ is singular.

let the eigen values of $A $ be $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ then $\det (A+I)=(1+\lambda_1)(1+\lambda_2)$

Also $\det A=\lambda_1\lambda_2$

then $\det (A+I)=(1+\lambda_1)(1+\lambda_2)=1+\lambda_1\lambda_2\implies \lambda_1+\lambda_2=-1\implies $ trace(A)=-1

so $3$ is gone.

how to choose the right one?

pLease help

Comment: try giving counter example for each options... this helps you in eliminating the wrong ones.

Comment: your approach is correct but you have made a mistake in simplification. You should get $\lambda_1$+$\lambda_2$=0. So option 3 is the correct one.

Comment: also there is a typo in your question. Last option should be "A is nonsingular" for otherwise option 1 and 4 mean the same

Comment: And you're supposing that $A$ is diagonalizable... That might not be the case.

Comment: The proof works because $A$ is trigonalizable over $\Bbb C$.@mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net how/why do you say that he is supposing that A is diagonalizable?

Comment: @shwetha How do you get the equality (in $\mathbb R$) $\det (A+I)=(1+\lambda_1)(1+\lambda_2)$? The eigenvalues may not be real.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net by the property that product of the eigenvalues is the det of that matrix. Does this property requires the eigenvalues to be real.

Comment: @shwetha what is *the set of that matrix*?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  sorry! It's a typo.... it should be determinant of that matrix

Comment: @shwetha The equality **in $\mathbb R$** requires $A$ to have two reals eigenvalues... that might not be the case.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I still don't get your point.... I don't think it's stated anywhere that the equality is in $\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: To state the point another way. What do you use as theorem, etc... to write $\det (A+I)=(1+\lambda_1)(1+\lambda_2)$? What matrix form as for determinant $(1+\lambda_1)(1+\lambda_2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in your equation, it should have been $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a &b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then 
$$\det(A+1)=\det \begin{pmatrix}
a+1 &b\\
c & d+1
\end{pmatrix}=(a+1)(d+1)-bc
$$
on the other hand
$$\det(A)+1=\det \begin{pmatrix}
a &b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}+1=ad-bc+1
$$

Since $\det(A+I)=\det A+1$ you can conclude that $a+d=0$, hence $tr A=0$.